# wordpress query string and array

Tags: wordpress

I'm building list of the posts from the first wordpress loop to remove it in the second one, to avoid duplicate content on the homepage. So I have an array:

```
$do_not_duplicate_slider[] = $post->ID;
```

Now I'd like to remove these posts from the secondary loop:

```
query_posts( 'order=DESC&orderby=modified&posts_per_page=4&post_type=post&category_name='.$myCity );
```

How do I pass $do_not_duplicate_slider in this string?

Under codex I read it is possible to do it in array like so: `post__not_in => $do_not_duplicate_slider`

But since my query is string based, I'd like to continue this way instead of rewriting everything in an array. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: 'implode' array to string will not work ?

Comment: @XMen should not there be wordpress native way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with :

```
query_posts( 'post__not_in='.join(',',$do_not_duplicate_slider).'&order=DESC&orderby=modified&posts_per_page=4&post_type=post&category_name='.$myCity );
```

Or with an array :

```
query_posts(array( 
    'post__not_in'=>$do_not_duplicate_slider,
    'order'=>'DESC',
    'orderby'=>'modified',
    'posts_per_page'=>4,
    'post_type'=>'post',
    'category_name'=>$myCity 
));
```

Comment: Yeah I went with second option. I knew this but was lazy :) but seems to be cleanest method.